# RequestedScope CDI bean null value

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am using JSF and CDI for my web app. I created a JSF form and a RequestScoped bean to hold form data. Then I created a CDI bean to process the form. Here is the form:

```
            <h:outputText value="Mailing Address: " />  
            <p:inputText value="#{profile.mailAddress}" />  

            <h:outputText value="Cell Phone: " />  
            <p:inputText value="#{profile.cellPhone}"/>  

            <h:outputText value="Home Phone: " />  
            <p:inputText value="#{profile.homePhone}"/>  

            <h:outputText value="Work Phone: " />  
            <p:inputText value="#{profile.workPhone}"/>
            <p:commandButton action="#{profileController.test}" value="submit" ajax="false" />
```

This is the request scoped bean:

```
package entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author G2
 */
@Named
@RequestScoped
@XmlRootElement
public class Profile implements Serializable{
    private String mailAddress;
    private String homePhone;
    private String workPhone;
    private String cellPhone;
    public String getMailAddress() {
        return mailAddress;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setMailAddress(String mailAddress) {
        this.mailAddress = mailAddress;
    }

    public String getHomePhone() {
        return homePhone;
    }

    public void setHomePhone(String homePhone) {
        this.homePhone = homePhone;
    }

    public String getWorkPhone() {
        return workPhone;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setWorkPhone(String workPhone) {
        this.workPhone = workPhone;
    }

    public String getCellPhone() {
        return cellPhone;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setCellPhone(String cellPhone) {
        this.cellPhone = cellPhone;
    }

}
```

and this is the CDI bean:

```
package jsf.classes;

import entities.Profile;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.Conversation;
import javax.enterprise.context.ConversationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

/**
 *
 * @author yg
 */
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class ProfileController implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private Profile current;
    @Inject
    private Conversation conversation;

    public Profile getSelected() {
        return current;
    }

    public void setSelected(Profile profile) {
        this.current = profile;
    }

    public void beginConversation() {
        if (conversation.isTransient()) {
            conversation.begin();
        }
    }

    public void endConversation() {
        if (!conversation.isTransient()) {
            conversation.end();
        }
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        beginConversation();
    }
}
```

However, when I entered values into the form and click submit, all properties in the profileController.current is null. How to let profileController receive the data I entered through the form?

Comment: Maybe wrong package of `RequestScoped` on `Profile` bean?Try to import it from `javax.enterprise.context`

Comment: Sorry, I have just changed the package but the problem still exists.

Comment: Does it work if you modify your form input text values to #{profileController.current.mailAddress}?